# Compressing files (gzip) in express js 4.4.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gzip

I' using express js app as a web server but all static content is unzipped (js and css files). I tried a couple of solutions like using compression https://github.com/expressjs/compression but can't get is working.
Here is the way I'm doing it (only the part relevant for compression usage):

```
var app = module.exports = express();
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());

var cacheTime = 86;     // 7 days
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public',{ maxAge: cacheTime }));

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Are you declaring the `express.static()` middleware _before_ the `compression()` middleware? Also, with Express you can use [`app.listen()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen) instead of having to use `http.createServer(app)...`

Comment: Yes, i'm using static() right before the compression()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Express middleware is always processed in order of declaration.

You have this:

```
app.use(express.static(...));
app.use(compression());
```

That means that a request is *first* processed by `express.static()`, and when it can handle such a request, it will generate a response immediately and the request will never be passed to the compression middleware.

If you swap the order of the middleware, like this:

```
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(...));
```

All requests will first pass through the compression middleware, which will set up things so responses will get compressed.

Comment: getting the same thing. I updated the quesion with full code

Comment: `compression` [by default](https://github.com/expressjs/compression#threshold) won't compress files smaller than 1kb